# Can I identify Outlook invites for meetings that have been and gone?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Before I open a meeting invite in Microsoft Outlook, is there an easy way to find out if the date and time of the meeting has already passed?

(This is useful if I’m away for a period of time and get invites to meeting that happened whilst I was away. By the time I get to see and open them, I’ve already missed the meeting.)

Comment: Check the deleted folder, there is also a setting to prevent automatic deletions>>>>https://www.bcti.com/2017/03/06/outlook-meeting-invitations-deleted-accepted/

Comment: @Moab The invite isn’t deleted though and is still sitting in my inbox - it’s just that the meeting has been and gone.

Answer (score 0):

For Outlook Invites, you need to Open the Invite. That is so you can action the invite (Accept or Decline).

At the time you open the Invite, you can see the subject and the time as well as attached documents. You make your decision to Accept (Decline) based on this information. When you open the invite, you can also see if the meeting time has passed.

Once you respond, the Invite goes to your Deleted Items folder and the response goes to Sent Items.  I delete the response also.

If you accept, the Invite and documents (if any) go into your Calendar.

Comment: This isn’t answering the question, which is how to identify invites which have already been and gone *without opening the invite*.

Comment: I have used Outlook for decades. You must open the old invite to find out about invites. There is no other way. If you deleted the invites (not kept them in your Deleted folder) then you must ask the person who sent the invite. If still in your inbox, you must open the invite.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in Outlook to achieve that. As a workaround, you could assign this Invitation message a color category and then turn to the Calendar view to check if the column with  this color category is located in the past date.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.